# Composing two maps

Tags: scala, dictionary

Is there a function in Scala to compose two maps or is flatMap a sensible approach?

```
scala> val caps: Map[String, Int] = Map(("A", 1), ("B", 2))
caps: Map[String,Int] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2)

scala> val lower: Map[Int, String] = Map((1, "a"), (2, "b"))
lower: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> caps.flatMap {
     | case (cap, idx) => Map((cap, lower(idx)))
     | }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(A -> a, B -> b)
```

Some syntactic sugar would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know `lower` will contain keys for all the values in `caps`, you can use `mapValues`:

```
scala> caps mapValues lower
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(A -> a, B -> b)
```

If you don't want or need a new collection, just a mapping, it's a little more idiomatic to use `andThen`:

```
scala> val composed = caps andThen lower
composed: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> composed("A")
res1: String = a
```

This also assumes there aren't values in `caps` that aren't mapped in `lower`.

Comment: Not worth adding my own answer, but if there are values that aren't mapped, then: `for { (k,v) <- caps; x <- lower.get(v) } yield k -> x`

Comment: It would be nice to have some join methods (e.g. `caps join lower`, `caps leftJoin lower`), I suppose these could be written as my own PartialFunctions.

Comment: @tysonjh: You can always use e.g. `val composed = caps.lift andThen (_ flatMap lower.lift)` if you want to guard against missing keys at either level.

Comment: @Rex wouldn't it be better to use `withDefaultValue`? i.e. `caps mapValues lower.withDefaultValue("?")`

Comment: @giladhoch - Depends on your use case.  That is another thing to do (i.e. leave sentinels for problematic values rather than omitting them).

Comment: @RexKerr - there's still something that bothers me a bit. if there are values that appear in `caps` but have no matching values in `lower`, then the solution you suggested fails to retrieve all possible values. i'll "upgrade" my suggestion. so how 'bout this: `caps mapValues lower.withDefault{i => caps.filter{case (_,v) => v == i}.keySet.head.toLowerCase}`

Comment: comparing the solutions with: `val lower: Map[Int, String] = Map((1, "a"))` & `val caps: Map[String, Int] = Map(("A", 1),("B",2))` we get: `Map(A -> a)` for your solution, `Map(A -> a, B -> ?)` for my first suggestion, and `Map(A -> a, B -> b)` for the last suggestion, which IMHO, is more concise.

Comment: @giladhoch - If you define a different desired behavior, you write different code.  My code solves the problem in general; yours solves it in the case where you can construct a sensible default from the key.  Depending on the use case, one or the other will be preferable.

Comment: @TravisBrown I've opted for lifting the partial functions to guard for the missing keys since it fits nicely into the for-comprehension I am using.  Very nicely done, thank you.