# Converting Function1 to Map in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to compose two maps and get a composed map in Scala. I am doing the following:

```
val m1=Map(1->'A',2->'C',3->'Z')
val m2=Map('A' -> "Andy", 'Z'->"Zee",'D'->"David")

val m3=m2.compose(m1)
```

Now m3 is m1;m2, but its type is Function1.

**Question:**
How can I convert Function1 to Map?

ps.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570216/composing-two-maps), instead of m2.compose(m1), it is suggested to use `val m3 = m1 andThen m2`. Anyways, the result is of type Function1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composing two maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570216/composing-two-maps)

Comment: I updated the question to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expext for non-existing keys? If yuo want to remove this values from map use

```
val m1: Map[Int, Char] = Map(1 -> 'A', 2 -> 'C', 3 -> 'Z')
val m2: Map[Char, String] = Map('A' -> "Andy", 'Z' -> "Zee", 'D' -> "David")
val m3: Map[Int, String] = m1.filter(x => m2.contains(x._2)).map(x => x._1 -> m2(x._2))
//Map(1 -> Andy, 3 -> Zee)
```

Skipping .filter(x => m2.contains(x._2)) with throw an exception for this situations

Comment: This will throw an exception if a value in the first map does not have a corresponding key in the second.

Comment: I came to ask a question - what do you expext for non-existing keys?

Comment: @DmitryMeshkov Your answer is wise and solves my problem; but since I updated the title of the question, the answer does not now directly address the question subject. I will wait to see if somebody possibly provides a direct answer (that is, how to convert  Function1 to map).

Comment: Your question in first formulation is not a dublicate and more useful)

Comment: The same thing could be done using `collect` : `m1.collect{ case (k, v) if m2.contains(v) =>  k -> m2(v)  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
val m3: Map[Int, String] = m1.mapValues(m2)
```

There is a caveat that despite the return type this will recalculate `m2(m1(x))` on every access to `m3(x)`, just like `m2.compose(m1)`.

> since I updated the title of the question, the answer does not now directly address the question subject. I will wait to see if somebody possibly provides a direct answer (that is, how to convert Function1 to map).

```
def funToMap[A, B](f: A => B): Map[A, B] = Map.empty[A, B].withDefault(f)
```

Comment: the f in withDefault is used only for the Map.apply method (and not for get or other methods)

Answer (score 1):

**Why composing two Maps gives you a Function1**

A `Map` offers the semantics of a `Function1` and then some. When you compose two `Map` functions, you get a new `Function1` because `compose` is an operation on functions.

So you should not expect to get a `Map` by composing two `Map`s -- you are just composing the function aspects of the `Map`s, not the `Map`s themselves.

**How to get a composed Map**

To actually compose two `Map`s into another `Map`, you can use `mapValues`, but be careful. If you do it like this:

```
val m3 = m1 mapValues m2
```

you will silently get a view (see [this bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4776)) rather than a simple map, so as you do lookups in `m3` it will really do lookups in `m1` and then in `m2`. For large `Map`s and few lookups, that's a win because you didn't process a lot of entries you didn't need to. But if you do lots of lookups, this can cause a serious performance problem.

To really make a new single `Map` data structure that represents the composition of `m1` and `m2` you need to do something like

```
val m3 = (m1 mapValues m2).view.force
```

That is kind of unfortunate. In a perfect world `m1 mapValues m2` would give you the new single composed `Map` -- and very quickly, by creating a new data structure with shape identical to `m1` but with values run through `m2` -- and `(m1 mapValues m2).view` would give you the view (and the type would reflect that).